PostgreSQL - Selecting from different schemas in the same database
Will creating a view Table in schema 2 that pulls data from Table on schema 1 , affect the database or cause any other issues?
my code:
CREATE VIEW "test"."Excavation" AS
SELECT *
FROM "public"."Distribution_UG";


Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please don't put your questions in bold type - it hurts my head! :-) Also, you had the post tagged wtih SQL Server and PostgreSQL as well as with various PostGIS tags - I'm going to assume PostgreSQL (since that's in the question subject also - correct as necessary. Why would SELECTing from a different schema within the same database cause a problem? Have you performed any tests?

@nbk - I'm not sure what you mean by the above - check here.

then answer the question#

Creating a view does not cause any performance problem as such. Schemas don't make a difference there; they are just a logical category.
Of course it can impact your performance if you use the view — just like running the defining query can impact performance, because it consumes resources.
